# How to get the Value of a Specific clicked div that's being Looped on (each)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

When i click on an Image i'm only getting the first Value regardless of which image i click on
, i want to get the value of the Specifically clicked image.. the value Would is the Pumpno..
as you can see i'm creating a name attribute to hold Pumpno Values is this the correct way ?? I even tried holding Pump Values in a Data-anyname(HTML5) and this only gives me the Last value for any Image that I clicked on...

the Script i'm trying to get the values from

```
function pumps() {
  $.get("Pumpstates", {}, function(data) {
      $(".pump_container").empty()
      var Pumpval;
      $.ajaxSetup({
        cache: false
      });

      $.each(data, function(index, value) {
          $(".pump_container").append('<div class="block_grid_three p' + value.pumpNo + '" name="' + value.pumpNo + '" />');

          $(".p" + value.pumpNo).append('<span class="pump_button pump_link" name="' + value.pumpNo + '" ' + value.pumpNo + ' "><div class="pump_block' + value.pumpNo + '"></div></span>');
          if (value.state <= 2) {
            $(".pump_block" + value.pumpNo).css('background-image', 'url("/PumpImages/Alien Icons-05.png")');

          } else if (value.state == 3 || value.state == 17) {
            $(".pump_block" + value.pumpNo).css('background-image', 'url("/PumpImages/Alien Icons-17.png")');

          } else if (value.state == 4) {
            $(".pump_block" + value.pumpNo).css('background-image', 'url("/PumpImages/pump_idle.gif")');

          } else if (value.state == 5 || value.state == 32) {
            $(".pump_block" + value.pumpNo).css('background-image', 'url("/PumpImages/pump_calling.gif")');


            $(".pump_block" + value.pumpNo).append(' <span class="pump_no">Pump: ' +
              value.pumpNo + '</span>');

            $(".pump_block" + value.pumpNo).append(' <span class="Goal"> volume :' +
              value.volume + '</span>');

            $(".pump_block" + value.pumpNo).append(' <span class="Goal">Price :' + value.price +
              '</span>');

            $('.p' + value.pumpNo).not(':last').remove();
          });
      });
  }

  /////////////////////////////////following Script is How i'm trying tp get the value////////////



  $(document).ready(function() {

    $(".pump_container").click(function() {

      var PumpNo = $(this).attr("name");

      $.ajax({
        type: "Post",
        url: "/Account/SelectedPumps",
        cache: false,
        data: {
          pumpNo: PumpNo
        },
        complete: function() {

        }

      })

    })
  })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue appears to be that the 'name' attribute is on `.block_grid_three`, not `.pump_container` so you probably want to put the click listener on that element. Because `.block_grid_three` is being created dynamically, we'll have to use [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/), like this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".pump_container").on('click', '.block_grid_three', function() {
    let PumpNo = $(this).attr("name");
    $.ajax({
      type: "Post",
      url: "/Account/SelectedPumps",
      cache: false,
      data: {  pumpNo: PumpNo },
      complete: function() { }
    })
  })
})
```

Comment: This worked thank you so Much Mate... Thank you... project is due in 3 days life saver